# Difference between className and classList

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Which one of the following should be preferred under what circumstances?

```
btnElement.classList.add('btn');

btnElement.className = 'btn';
```

Comment: One *adds* a class, the other *sets* the entire class string. Try it on an element that has any other classes and you'll see a difference.

Comment: [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className); [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Answer (score 5):

> Using "classList", you can add or remove a class without affecting any
> others the element may have. But if you assign "className", it will
> wipe out any existing classes while adding the new one (or if you
> assign an empty string it will wipe out all of them).
>
> Assigning "className" can be a convenience for cases where you are
> certain no other classes will be used on the element, but I would
> normally use the "classList" methods exclusively.
>
> And "classList" also has handy "toggle" and "replace" methods.

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/difference-between-classlist-and-classname

Answer (score 1):

ClassList as the name suggest is the list of classes in an element.

If you have multiple classes on an element and you want to add/remove one without altering the rest you should use `classList`.

`classList` also provides methods like `toggle` which are really useful.

```js
function toggleClass(){
  let txt = document.querySelector("h2");
  txt.classList.toggle("changebg");
}
```

```css
.font-style {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.changebg {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="font-style" >Hello World!</h2>
<button onclick='toggleClass()'>Toggle Background Class</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "classList", you can add or remove a class without affecting any others the element may have. But if you assign "className", it will wipe out any existing classes while adding the new one (or if you assign an empty string it will wipe out all of them)

**classList**

Using classList, you can add or remove a class without affecting any other classes the element may have.

So this is helpful for adding additional classes to an element that contain other classes.

classList has some handy methods like toggle and replace.

```
if (clicked) {
    button.classList.add('clicked');
} else {
    button.classList.remove('clicked');
}
```

Here if the button was clicked it will add the clicked class along with other classes the element may have and it will remove only the clicked class from the element.

**className**

If you use className, it will wipe out any existing classes while adding the new one (or if you assign an empty string it will wipe out all of them).

Using className can be convenience when you know this element will not use any other classes.

```
if (clicked) {
    button.className = 'clicked';
} else {
    button.className = '';
}
```

In this case, className will wipe all the classes the element may have and add clicked class to it. The empty string('') will wipe all the classes.

**Conclusion**

the recommendation would be to use className whenever possible.

Use classList when you need classList methods like toggle, replace, etc.

**context** https://dev.to/microrony/difference-between-classlist-and-classname-45j7

Comment: "*My recommendation would be to use className whenever possible.*" that is counter to my own conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the changes in **JavaScript** to apply same difference one with use of `classList` and other with `className` .

It will be clear from 1st btn only that `classList` add extra name in `class` while `className` replaces the whole `class` (only `.border` is applied) .
Further are different function of `classList` which cannot be achieved by `className` and at last 4 line of code is reduced to 1 liner with use of `toggle` .

> So you should look to your needs : Like, if you want to completely replace the `class` property names than use `className` else you can use `classList` property with different methods `.add()` `.remove()` `.replace()` `.toggle()` to only have changes in specific without hampering all names of `class`

> Instruction for below snippet : Reload the snippet when you click one button so that clear differences can be seen on next btns

```js
var classList1 = document.getElementById("part1")
var classname2 = document.getElementById("part2")

function funcAdd() {
  classList1.classList.add("border");
  classname2.className = "border";
}

function funcRemove() {
  classList1.classList.remove("color");
  classname2.style.color = "black";
}

function funcReplace() {
  classList1.classList.replace("background", "background1");
  classname2.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
}

function funcToggle() {
  classList1.classList.toggle("color1");
  if (classname2.style.color == "gold") {
    classname2.style.color = "blue";
  } else {
    classname2.style.color = "gold";
  }
}
```

```css
.background {
  background-color: red
}

.background1 {
  background-color: lightgreen
}

.color {
  color: blue
}

.font {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.border {
  border: 10px solid black
}

.color1 {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="part1" class="background color font">classList</div>
<br><br><br>

<div id="part2" class="background color font">className</div>
<br><br><br>

<button onclick="funcAdd()">Add a border class</button>
<button onclick="funcRemove()">Remove a color class</button>
<button onclick="funcReplace()">Replace a background class</button>
<button onclick="funcToggle()">Toggle a color class</button>
<br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just known one thing difference between className and classList. className returns string within they are names of the current element and classList also returns names but as an array.

Comment: `classList` isn't an array :x